# Find the size of two-dimensional unsized array and print all its elements

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, null

I've been learning C and came across this exercise:

> Given this two-dimensional unsized array:
>
> ```
> char list_ch[][2] = {
>     '1', 'a',
>     '2', 'b',
>     '3', 'c',
>     '4', 'd',
>     '5', 'e',
>     '6', 'f',
> };
> ```
>
> write a program to measure the total bytes taken by the array, and then print out all elements of the array.

I've tried to accomplish it using two `for` loops:

```
int main() {
    char list_ch[][2] = {
        '1', 'a',
        '2', 'b',
        '3', 'c',
        '4', 'd',
        '5', 'e',
        '6', 'f'
    };
    int i;
    int k;
    int size = 0;
    for (i = 0; list_ch[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            size++;
            printf("%c ", list_ch[i][k]);
        };
    };
    printf("%d", size);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the program prints a long sequence of different characters and doesn't print the size. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof list_ch` gives you the size of the full array.  The number of individual elements is generally derived from that via division.

Comment: `for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof list_ch / sizeof *list_ch; i += 1 ){ ... `

Comment: The problem here is that there is no ```'\0'``` character in the array, so your code invokes an infinite loop, reading past the memory you have allocated until it finds a ```'\0'``` byte. This results in undefined behaviour. You shouldn't be attempting to read more than what you've allocated. Aside: The common idiom in C to determine the size of an array is to use the ```sizeof``` operator to determine the size of the full array, and then divide it by the size of one of its element to get the total number of elements in the array.

Comment: Tried to go with the solution proposed in the tutorial. Seems I havent full understood it.
Thanks for the help @WilliamPursell @kjhayes!

Comment: @kjhayes @Haris, notice `list_ch[i] != '\0'` is not correctly  searching for a _null character_.   `list_ch[i]` is an _array_, not a `char`.  IAC, its never 0, so code jumps off the deep end.

Answer (score 2):

`list_ch[i] != '\0'` always fails.  It is a curious mis-coding too as `list_ch[i]` is a 1D array and comparing an array to a *null character* implies that misunderstanding.

`list_ch[i]`, as an *array*, is never 0.  All address of *arrays* are never 0.  (Pointers can be 0 - but that is another story).

Eventually code attempts to access out of array bounds, leading to *undefined behavior* UB.

---

Use `sizeof` to discern the 2D array attributes. [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880806/find-the-size-of-two-dimensional-unsized-array-and-print-all-its-elements-in-c/74882627#comment132146734_74880806)

**Total bytes**

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof list_ch);
```

**Dimensions**

```
size_t rows = sizeof list_ch / sizeof list_ch[0];
size_t cols = sizeof list_ch[0] / sizeof list_ch[0][0];
```

**print all its elements**

```
for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  const char *sep = "";
  for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    printf("%s%c ", sep, list_ch[r][c]);
    sep = " "; 
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```